How to print comma symbol as part of clist value
This is what I tried:
\clist_new:N \g_conclusions_clist
\clist_set:Nn \g_conclusions_clist
{
    Value\, value\, value!,
    another value!
}

\clist_item:Nn \g_conclusions_clist 1

I escaped commas with , it works, but they don't appear in the document. It outputs value value value!.

\, makes it not a comma for the clist but makes it the standard command \, which is a thin space.

The proper syntax would be \clist_item:Nn \g_conclusions_clist {1}. Always brace n-type arguments.

You can use brace groups
{Value, value, value!}, another value!

